# How can I create a greedy algorithm for this “balls and boxes” knapsack-like problem?

Tags: algorithms

Say that there are $n$ balls, each with weight at most 1. We can assume that the weights of these balls are put in an array $W[1\ldots n]$ with $0 \le W[i] \le1$ for all $i$. The problem is to put these balls in a minimum number of boxes so that each box contains no more than two balls, and the total weight of the balls placed in each box is $\le 1$.

I am to design an efficient greedy algorithm for this. I presume that one obvious choice (pick the largest first and the smallest second) is not correct. But what if I picked the largest available ball first, and then the largest remaining that fits second? I think this is right, but I'm not sure how to prove this. Doing this would produce a trivial $O(n^2)$ algorithm.

This also seems like some kind of variant on the knapsack problem, but there the greedy algorithm is not optimal.

Comment: I think that this "greedy" is optimal. Moreover, if you do store values in a binary search tree then finding the maximal second stone that has weight $\le 1 - x$, where $x$ is the weight of the first stone is $O(\log n)$, not $O(n)$, making the overall algorithm $O(n \log n)$.

Comment: Btw, as you may know `std::set` from C++ actually does not support `std::lower_bound` in $O(\log n)$, but you only need to erase from your BST, which means that you don't need rebalancing and can implement your own BST pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks. The implementation is not relevant to the problem but the overall design with the BST seems sound.